# Fullstack module reuse with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, react-fullstack

I'm working on a project that uses typescript on both backend (nodejs) and front-end. The project has some cryptography involved which means I'm using [WebCrypto](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/) - on the backend I use [`node-webcrypto-ossl`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-webcrypto-ossl) as a shim so I may share code between the client and the server.

Is there a way to make a module export one thing on the client and another on the server so I may just do `import * as crypto from './webcrypto'` to expose a the interface in a common manner?

On the server it should export `node-webcrypto-ossl` and on the client just expose `window.crypto`.

I tried various things but webpack keeps attempting to pull `node-webcrypto-ossl` into the browser which unsurprisingly fails.

Here's my (failed) attempt:

```
let crypto = null;

if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    const WebCrypto = require('node-webcrypto-ossl');
    crypto = new WebCrypto();
} else {
    crypto = window.crypto;
}

export {
    crypto as webcrypto
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approach itself is mostly correct, you may need configure webpack's `externals` to keep `node-webcrypto-ossl` to be loaded in nodejs context only. Shortest pseudo looks like

```
webpack.config.js
...
externals: {
  'node-webcrypto-ossl: {
    commonjs: 'node-webcrypto-ossl'
   },
```

then webpack will not try to bundle specific module but leave `require` as is for those modules.

In addition to those, you may able to configure `definePlugin` as well for node.js / browser context so your crypto module can be statically compiled for each environment in build time, instead of looking object in runtime.

Comment: Thanks! How would type "forwarding" work in this case?